# jquery onchange/onblur event

Tags: jquery, events

Hy guys, I am tring to fire a function on a input. The code is correct but something strange happens. If I change the 
value of the input and clicks anywhere in the page the value of the 
input becomes: `$ 2323,44` (for example). But, if I leave the input after
changing it using the tab key, the function is called `( the alert message is fired)` 
but the value of the input does not stays with the `$`. When I am debuging with firebug
it works like a charm in both situation. Anybody has any suggestion? I've tried using the onblur event and the same thing happens.

```
 <input id='TEST'  onchange='validate($(this))'/>

  function validate(field) {
    var value = $(field).val();
     /*...some logic here ...*/

    if (value > MaxExample) {
        $(field).val('$ 0,00');
        clearInputsOfTheTable();
        alert("Max");
    } else if (value < MinExample) {
        $(field).val('$ 0,00');
        clearInputsOfTheTable();
        alert("Min");
    } else {
        $(field).val( "$ " + valorFinal);
        alert("good");
        clearInputsOfTheTable();
        otherFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's Spanish for `field`. I think he did an incomplete job of translating his example from Spanish to English.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What happens if you take out the calls to `clearInputsOfTheTable` and `otherFunction`?

Comment: These funtions are responsible for cleaning the inputs of the table and setting then to disable and for adding a button in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foucusout` event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#TEST').focusout(function(){


var value = $(campo).val();
 /*...some irelevant logic here ...*/

if (value > MaxExample) {
    $(campo).val('$ 0,00');
    clearInputsOfTheTable();
    alert("Max");
} else if (value < MinExample) {
    $(campo).val('$ 0,00');
    clearInputsOfTheTable();
    alert("Min");
} else {
    $(campo).val( "$ " + valorFinal);
    alert("good");
    clearInputsOfTheTable();
    otherFunction();
}

})

})
```

Comment: Btw, I have solved the problem using a Jquery plugin called MoneyMask.js. And I have used the values for 'Real' the  national currency in Brazil! 

I really apreciate your help!